# Interpretation of two independet solutions of equations of motion in AdS/CFT

Tags: gravity, gauge-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, duality

I am trying to understand the statement in AdS/CFT correspondence, that from the two independent solutions of equations of motion in the bulk, one corresponds to the source of operator $\mathcal{O} (x)$, and another one for the source of this operator $\phi_0 (x)$. So by advice of one professor I have began reading article by Klebanov and Witten https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9905104.pdf. And there are some points, which I would like to clarify, although, I suppose that the question itself may sound dumb.

The expression for massive scalar field action in $AdS_{d+1}$ is:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int dx^{d} dz \ z^{-d+1} \left[ (\partial_z \phi)^2 + (\partial_i \phi)^2 + \frac{m^2}{z^2} \phi^2 \right] 
$$
Near the boundary $(z \rightarrow 0 )$, one searches for the solution in form:
$$
\phi(z, x) = z^{\Delta} (\phi_0 (x) + \mathcal{O} (z^2)) 
$$
The $\Delta$ in the exponent corresponds to the scaling dimension of the field, and there are two solutions for the field:
$$
\Delta_{\pm} = \frac{d}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{d}{2}^2 + m^2}
$$

1) From the initial expression for the action, it can be seen that in order to converge - $2 \Delta - d > 0$. Then the integration by parts is done, and we  have following expression:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int dx^{d} dz \ z^{-d-1} \phi( -\nabla^2 + m^2) \phi
$$
And it is said, that now action converges, whether $2 \Delta - d > -2$. But seemingly, the divergence is the same as before, because the mass term is the same, and term with $\partial_z^2 \phi$ would have same divergence as before. Where I am getting wrong?

2)  Is it correct to think about the formula for the field in the bulk:
$$
\phi (z, x) = \int d^d x^{'} K_\Delta (z, x, x^{'}) \phi_0 (x^{'}) 
$$ 
As an evolution from any point at the boundary to this, or there are any caveats.

3) In this specific case, the relationship between the expectation value of an operator and the subdominant term, is deduced by checking the expressions (2.12) and (2.16) in the paper concerned. The question is : is there a theorem, that this statement holds for any kind of source and operator, or it is specific for the scalar operators in $AdS_{p+1}$.

I would really appreciate, if one clarified these points to me.